# How to execute SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I've done an export of a table (using the wizard) I saved the package and I see it in the msdb.sysssispackages table. But it doesn't show up in the Integration Services Catalogue section. So how can I make it show up so I can execute this package again?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2016, why are you using `msdb` deployment and not the SSIS Catalog? SSISDB is a far better deployment method.

Comment: @larnu I used the wizard to do the export and at the end it asked me to save the package.

Comment: That would export it to a dtsx file. To deploy to SSISDB you would need to add that file to your SSIS Project, and then deploy.

Comment: `msdb` isn't SSISDB. They are completely different deployment methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing it through SQL Agent, the Package Source is SQL Server for packages stored in the msdb

[image]

A confusing bit of terminology that I started to respond with on your deleted question is that you can store a package in SQL Server and that usually means the msdb.dbo.sysssispackages table. But we also have the project deployment model, which deploys an .ispac file into the SSISDB.

If you want a package to be in the SSISDB that is not of the project deployment model, the 2016(?) release of SSIS allowed for an Incremental package deployment for a project deployment model. You *could* use that approach to uplift your msdb based SSIS package into a new "project" without ever opening Visual Studio to create an actual solution.

That's a technical answer, it can be done that way but I would advise against it as you generally want to source control any processes that you operationalize.

Comment: is there anyway to edit the package that is stored in the  msdb.sysssispackages table ?

Comment: No, not particularly. You can [export the package to disk](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html), edit it with SSDT/Visual Studio and then import it back to the table.

Comment: thanks. do you know why is it that the export table wizard succeeds just fine using "OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" as my destination but when I run the package per your instructions I get "The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered"? It's obviously installed because the wizard used it.

Comment: You need to run in 32 bit mode as that's the only version of JET. The default is to run the 64 bit version of DTEXEC. In my screenshot, go to the Execution Options tab and there should be a checkbox for Use 32 bit run-time